# Recruiting officer on a a non-residential level?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Is it possible to use a recruiting officer on a non-residential level to get dream jobs? I've filled ever dream job slot except for the Livestock Exchange, and now that they raised the price of filling an empty apartment, it's a LOT harder to get those dream jobs. If I had a spare residential level, I could use it to hold extras and swap them in, but I don't have one of those either, so I'm kinda screwed otherwise.

Barring that, is there any GOOD way to fill those missing dream jobs?

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain that you can ONLY use a recruiting officer on a residential level.  When I've tried to send them anywhere else, they merely get off the elevator and do nothing.

Comment: Can confirm. Recruiting officer does nothing on non-residential levels.

Answer (score 0):

2 additional residential levels have been added to the game, update as of 2/7/2014. I believe you can utilize these 2 levels as spare residential level, to swap dream job citizens in.